# JQM (jQueryMobile) HTML5 Form Validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-mobile, jquery-1.5

I've found this [h5validate](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/) plugin but having no luck with it when using it with jQM, anyone have any suggestions on html5 form validation w/ jQm?

I have multiple forms that need to be validated, which are also loaded via AJAX.

Here is the workflow:

- Load main form, when page is loading bind with live() (this adds the jQM functionality).
- On submission (which is a button click) load the next form via AJAX (The next form goes through the same logic on loading)
- This is where I want to add the form validation, if valid submit and load the next form, else display errors

Need to add form validation for each form and wanted to take advantage of the html5 syntax, that's why I liked the h5validate plugin but everything I try nothing happens, ugh...

I've also looked at the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) but the additional syntax and markup is something I'm trying to avoid.
And I've looked at [HTML5FORM](http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/ajax-jquery-validation-html5-form.html) but it is using jQuery 1.4.2 and I'm using 1.5.x

Wanted to know if anyone else had any luck with html5 and multi form validation submission?

Comment: I'm the author of h5Validate. I'd love to take a look at the code you were trying to use when "nothing happened". h5Validate is a thoroughly tested project, in use on some very high traffic projects. If something is broken, I'd love to get some test cases so I can fix it. - Eric

Comment: Sorry this was a while ago, I used another validation library. You might want to look at jQueryMobile and how your plugin interacts with it as it's gaining popularity. I would be happy to help test the process if you would like? LMK

Comment: Please post a bug report and test case at https://github.com/dilvie/h5Validate/issues/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had success with multi forms with the validationEngine.js plugin from here http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

Example here: http://coww.ws/jqmtest/

Hope this helps?

Comment: the form does look nice (I like the icons as well) but if you view it on a mobile device (iP4) the error divs display up at the top of the page instead of over the element that it's for

Answer (score 2):

[ValidVal](http://validval.frebsite.nl/) is what I'm going with, it has all the simple syntax and takes advantage of the html5 attributes for validation

Comment: A big problem with this library though is that even though it lets you handle when the form is invalid, it doesn't tell you why. You have to check the inputs yourself to generate a relevant error message (by default it displays a generic message in an alert for the entire form).